# SQL query only working with one column and stops working as soon as I add the second column

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I've being trying to make this query work but I haven't managed to make it do so, here is what I've managed to do so far:

```
select c.EID
from certified c
    inner join aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
group by c.EID 
HAVING count(c.EID)  >= 3 and MAX(a.CRUISINGRANGE);
```

RESULTS:

```
EID
'141582651'

'142519864'

'269734834'

'390487451'

'552455318'

'556784565'

'567354612'

'573284895'
```

As you can see, I have an inner join with the aircraft table in order to get the max cruising range, from certified I count and return the pilots that can pilot more than 3 planes.

Now my issue is, I can't seem to be able to add the a.AID on my select in order to display it, here's what I've tried:

```
select c.EID, a.AID
from certified c
    inner join aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
group by c.EID, a.AID
HAVING count(c.EID)  >= 3 and MAX(a.CRUISINGRANGE);
```

RESULTS:

EID  AID

0rows

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
EID          AID

'141582651'  '6475'

'142519864'  '8430'

'269734834'   '8430'

'390487451'   '7120'

'552455318'   '3383'

'556784565'   '7120'

'567354612'   '8430'

'573284895'   '7120'
```

but I get 0 rows while trying to do so.

```
DATA SAMPLE: 
Certified: 
EID        AID
142519864   1
269734834   1
550156548   1
567354612   1
11564812    2
141582651   2
142519864   2
242518965   2
269734834   2
552455318   2
556784565   2


AIRCRAFTS
AID    ANAME         CRUISING RANGE
1   Boeing 747-400  8430
2   Boeing 737-800  3383
3   Airbus A340-300 7120
4   British Aerospace Jetstream 41  1502
5   Embraer ERJ-145 1530
6   SAAB 340    2128
7   Piper Archer III    520
8   Tupolev 154 4103
9   Lockheed L1011  6900
10  Boeing 757-300  4010
11  Boeing 777-300  6441
12  Boeing 767-400ER    6475
13  Airbus A320 2605
14  Airbus A319 1805
15  Boeing 727  1504
16  Schwitzer 2-33  30
123 Airbus  1000
302 Boeing  5000
306 Jet01   5000
378 Airbus380   8000
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.  You might be surprised, but a non-functioning query is not necessarily a good way to communicate intentions.

Comment: you have a incompletw condition for having `and MAX(a.CRUISINGRANGE)`   ... should be `and MAX(a.CRUISINGRANGE) > 10`

Comment: add a  proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge, actually it is complete, each plane has a different cruising range, eg: AID= 100, cruisingrange = 8000, AID = 101, cruisingrange = 300.

Now if a pilot can pilot these two, my "and MAX(a.CRUISINGRANGE);" will allow to display only the AID of the aircraft with the highest cruising range.

Comment: add  also the expected  result

Comment: @Coldhands . . . That might be what you *want* the code to do.  But that is not how SQL works.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want would really help.

Comment: looking to your data you have not  `count(c.EID)  >= 3`  each  EID is different you are counting for the value that are repeated  3 or more times

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, each EID represents a pilot, and each AID represents an aircraft, so I'm basically counting the EID duplications in order to determine if the pilot can pilote 3 or more airplanes, which is why I'm using count(c.EID).

Comment: add  the expected  result  .....................

Comment: @GordonLinoff explanation and sample data added.

Comment: Expected result added as well

Comment: Be careful asking for MAX() on strings that contain numbers.. `'9'` is a lot greater than `'1000000'`

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification. You are not saying how output is a function of input. You only say some redundant things about a wrong query. Tell us exactly what rows need to appear in the output given what rows are in the input or what rows are in the result & each input given a situation. Please clarify via edits not comments. Please format your tables without blanks & with columns aligned. Input tables should also be initialization DDL. PS Read an intro or manual re group by, aggregate functions & having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really hard to follow; you don't seem to have actually stated what you want in a consistent and coherent manner. From reading the comments it seems that you would like to know:

The furthest that each pilot (who is rated for 3 or more aircraft) may fly.

You are thus expecting a list of pilots EIDs, and the max cruising range (from the aircraft table) across all the planes that pilot may fly. The pilot must be able to fly at least 3 planes.

Steps:

Build the list of pilots and the distances the aircraft they are rated for can fly:

```
SELECT c.EID, a.cruising_range
FROM certified c INNER JOIN aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
```

Improve the query to count the ratings and the max cruising range per pilot (A pilot can fly a plane, a plane has a range, therefore when a pilot is flying a plane, a pilot has a range):

```
SELECT c.EID, COUNT(*) as count_ratings, MAX(a.cruising_range) max_range
FROM certified c INNER JOIN aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
GROUP BY c.EID --per pilot
```

Improve the query to select only the pilots who can fly at least 3 aircraft:

```
SELECT c.EID, max_range FROM
(
  SELECT c.EID, COUNT(*) as count_ratings, MAX(a.cruising_range) max_range
  FROM certified c INNER JOIN aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
  GROUP BY c.EID --per pilot
) pilot_ranges
WHERE
  pilot_ranges.count_ratings >= 3
```

I could have used HAVING:

```
SELECT c.EID, MAX(a.cruising_range) max_range
FROM certified c INNER JOIN aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
GROUP BY c.EID 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

But sometimes there's a benefit in laying out the query visually in a set-of-steps-rather-than-trying-to-do-it-all-at-once, and using subqueries to mentally form a list of data, then change it, filter it, add to it.. all in stages.

The query optimizer will likely rewrite these queries internally so they end up executing identically anyway, so the benefit is for the human in understanding and future maintenance

Edit: Here's a query that lists the EID and AID for every pilot-aircraft combination, where the pilot is capable of flying 3+ planes:

```
SELECT c.EID, a.AID FROM
(
  SELECT c.EID
  FROM certified c
  GROUP BY c.EID 
  HAVING count(*) >= 3
) find_pilots_can_fly_atleast_three
INNER JOIN certified c ON c.EID = find_pilots_can_fly_atleast_three.EID
INNER JOIN aircrafts a ON c.AID = a.AID
```

First you generate a list of pilots that are interesting - that's the subuery `find_pilots_can_fly_atleast_three`, then we join that data back to certified and aircrafts. We end up with a list of pilots who can fly 3 planes, and we get details about the planes

You might have been trying to do too much in one go. When you group, you lose certain bits of data. In grouping up the pilots in order to find those who can fly 3+ planes, we MUST lose the aircraft ID, and keep only the pilot ID. If you try and keep the aircraft ID (because you want it), you end up with groups that only have a count of 1, because each pilot-aircraft combination is unique. So, we lose the aircraft id into an aggregation (count) and keep the pilot id. This helps us find out how many planes each pilot can fly.
To find out *which* planes those pilots can fly, we MUST then join that pilot id from the "find 3+" query back to the list of pilot-aircrafts (certified table) to expand it back to a list of pilots-with-aircraft

Always remember that you're allowed to join a table to itself, and indeed it's vital in cases like this. If you had a table full of addresses with dates when you lived at that address, to find the latest one, you'd have a query that got `your_id, max(lived_there_until_date` but you can't keep any of the other address data - you want the date of the latest record.. And then if you DO want the rest of the data from that latest row, you join the query you just did back onto addresses table to retrieve the entire row with the latest lived_there_until date

Comment: Though I only need to select EID and AID on your 3rd and final query, is there a way to not select max(a.cruising_range) and instead put it in a where? or in group by / having?

Comment: Actually, our database is set on "set session sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';"

What I need to find is :
SELECT c.EID, a.AID

Though I can't use this select since our database requires us to group by the whole select group...

Anyway to get around it?

Comment: I'm confused. Where did you see me do a `select eid, aid`? Every database in the world requires you to either group or aggregate columns.. Are you now saying that you want is a list of pilots and aircraft, every pilot and every aircraft they can fly (but maybe you only want pilots who can fly at least 3 aircraft)? Why do you want to put the max range in a where/having? You definitely didn't say anything originally about the cruising range being a factor in where a pilot gets listed?!

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion but that is indeed what I want, and I can't seem to manage to aggregate the selects.